# Git Hub local clone with Mac

Tags: git, macos, github

I would like to be able to view the website of a github clone on my Mac. Successfully installed https://mac.github.com but this tool only allows viewing the github website directly at the central hosting location.

How can I locally view a github clone on my Mac? Is there an easy solution that requires minimal or no terminal commands? Alternatively, is there a complicated solution with a usable, comprehensive, step-by-step tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about opening the file locally? For instance finding the html file in your finder and opening it in a browser as file://user/xyz/file.html?

If so, when you clone the repository, it should show up in the bar on the left that lists all repositories installed on your machine, you should be able to open the context menu on a specific repository and click on "View in Finder". That should bring you to your local repository to view all the files. Then you can open the HTML file in the repo :D.

Comment: If this doesn't work, I believe the default place to see your repositories is your Home folder on Mac. You can try heading there. Each repository will have its own folder.

Comment: Yes, I can access the folder and each of the files. Editing also no problem. However, there is no single file that when clicked would open the website correctly if simply displayed with a browser. The landing page html file, for example, would only include text but no design elements when clicked. With ubuntu, I would change the localhost references in the exampe-nginx.conf, start nginx and then view the exact same files properly by typing "localhost: 8000" in the browser. I assume there is similar software for Mac that helps accessing github files through localhost?